# How to Overcome the default alert message in window.onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, window.onunload

I use window.onbeforeunload i have my own custom alert message but along with my message some default message is also showing in that confirm window. I need only my custom message.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way you can do that. it's default functionality of browser.

Comment: Thanks Rahul,But there is any other function that i want to used as a custom message alone.And also i want to know were is Window.onunload function it is in any js file?